# Does "such as" require an adjective?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, syntactic-analysis, sentence

Someone changed a sentence in a Wikipedia article from

> These cassettes became associated with genres **like** Gipsy rhumba, light
> music and joke tapes.

to

> These cassettes became associated with genres **such as** Gipsy rhumba,
> light music and joke tapes.

To me it feels wrong, but I cannot pinpoint what exactly is wrong. If "genres" had an additional qualifier that would need to be expounded, like "unpretentious", or "low-brow", or "mass-market", then "such as" variant would work for me:

> These cassettes became associated with unpretentious genres **such as** Gipsy rhumba,
> light music and joke tapes.

Am I not getting something here?

Comment: The *music* is like those genres, but the genres *have* those names. They are genre names, not names that genres might have. It is a list of example genres to which the music might belong. The edit is good.

Comment: About the adjective you would like to see. Suppose we go hiking and take fast food such as pasties, fruit and nuts. They don't need to be qualified.

Comment: *Such as* and *like* are alike in that they both mean **having the same qualities as**. The relevant qualities, however, need not be made explicit. 'Genres such as Gipsy rhumba' thus means genres having the same qualities as Gipsy rhumba, whatever these qualities are.

Comment: @WeatherVane "Suppose we go hiking and take fast food such as pasties, fruit and nuts. They don't need to be qualified."— you put a qualifier, "fast". It works for me. Without it, "Suppose we go hiking and take food such as pasties, fruit and nuts" does not sit well with me.

Comment: Both *like* and *such as* introduce examples. It seems petty to edit someone else's draft for so small a difference.

Comment: I disagree, they are not synonyms. "Like something" means similar, and "such as" introduces actual examples. The post is listing actual genres, not possibililties, because it says "became associated with" those particular genres. The edit may have been pedantic, but it is not wrong.

Comment: @RustyCore what if I said “Suppose we go hiking and take fast food such as McDonalds.” Do you think this sentence is wrong since fast food in this context is a noun in itself?

Comment: @CottonHeadedNinnymuggins "fast food such as McDonalds" sounds ok to me, "food such as McDonalds" does not.

Comment: @RustyCore why do you think it’s wrong? I honestly have 0 idea why you think it’s wrong if it doesn’t have an adjective. Fast food can be a noun as well can’t it?